# Better logging than /var/log/dpkg.log of package-management?

Tags: debian, apt, logs, package-management, aptitude

Has there been some better logging tools than `/var/log/dpkg.log` as `/var/log/dpkg.log` seems to have just installations and upgrades but nothing about removals . Also it seems a bit chaotic, does anybody know of a better method/system.

I am looking for something which you can read and is bit of structured information at least in the way it is presented.

Comment: See the files in `/var/log/apt`.

Comment: That's actually what i wanted to see, that has much more info. then /var/log/dpkg.log and done in much better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken.  `/var/log/dpkg.log` lists all installs, upgrades, removes and purges on the system.

e.g. the package most recently removed on my debian sid system was:

```
# grep remove /var/log/dpkg.log | tail -1
2015-10-08 17:21:56 remove libsmokebase3v5:amd64 4:4.14.3-1 <none>
```

It does log a lot of information, which can be "noise" if you're just interested in finding out which packages got installed or removed recently and when.  As always, filtering out "noise" from log files is an art.  Start with something like:

```
grep -E ' (install|upgrade|remove|purge) ' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Note the leading and trailing spaces around `(...)`...that prevents the regexp from matching those words if they happen to be embedded in a package name.